WordPress post_link produces permalink that cannot be visited
I write the following codes to change the permalinks of posts with some specific categories, as below:
/* 2024-12-04: Define custom permalinks for some specific posts */
function post_custom_permalink($permalink, $post) {
    // Check if post belongs to some specific categories
    if (has_category('case-studies', $post)) {
        $permalink = home_url('case-studies/' . $post->post_name . '/');
        return $permalink;
    }
    else if (has_category('guides', $post)) {
        $permalink = home_url('guides/' . $post->post_name . '/');
        return $permalink;
    }
    else if (has_category('tools', $post)) {
        $permalink = home_url('tools/' . $post->post_name . '/');
        return $permalink;
    }    
    
    // For all other cases, return the original permalink
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter('post_link', 'post_custom_permalink', 10, 2);

Now the problem is: when I create a post "Test Tool" with category tools, its permalink is shown as https://www.sample.com/tools/test-tool/.
But when I visit https://www.sample.com/tools/test-tool/, I will get 404 not found error. If I visit https://www.sample.com/test-tool/, I can see the post. Why?

the code is working fine on my test environment. Perhaps a conflict with a plugin or the .htaccess?

Could it be you are using the filter on custom post types? In which case you would use post_type_link filter.

@gael, the change to the permalinks are for normal posts, so I use post_link instead of post_type_link. Are you able to visit https://www.sample.com/tools/test-tool/ without getting a 404?

sample.com is a registered domain name. You should use example.com for your posts instead. That said, on my test environment, I am able to visit example.com/tools/test-tools without a 404 but the function is not working on Caleb environment neither. My permalink structure in wp settings > Permalinks: Custom Structure /%category%/%postname%/ are you using a custom structure to?

@gael, I know the reason now. My permalink structure is /%postname%/, so when WordPress see example.com/tools/test-tool/, it don't know how to process it. but yours is /%category%/%postname%/, so it can process and take tools as category.

Using the post_link filter only changes the link, it doesn't inform WordPress' rewrite rules about the permalink change. To support the change, use the add_rewrite_rule() function to define the additional rule for accessing posts (untested):
add_action( 'init', static function () : void {
   add_rewrite_rule( '^case-studies/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    ...
} );

Remember to flush the rewrite rules after implementing.

That was my idea but when I tested @alancc function on my test environment, the permalinks are renamed and the posts keep the new name in the url and the desired content.

Strange: OP's code and going to a post assigned to case-studies category 404s for me (https://cln.sh/ww54Vjz7).
